# in the dark about ajax instructions on arrays inside Autocomplete widget

Tags: arrays, jquery, firebug, jquery-autocomplete

I have an Autocomplete working with geonames.org cities in the source: option and want to manipulate some of the arrays in the results. I have a "hard coded" test version running, but am having trouble manipulating the array variables to turn it into something useful.

A short statement of the problem is I can't get the alert statements to output readable strings. I get [object, Object] types of output. I need readable strings in the arrays for other code (not shown) to work. But other problems are: the Firebug Console output does not occur, and the Console gives me the following error statement - Error: Permission denied to access property 'item.autocomplete' - from line 2 of jQuery. This does not happen with the hard coded test.  This is my first time using .grep and I'm not comfortable with .map, so I'm pretty sure the problems are array manipulations in those 3 sections.

Here's some relevant code. All the variables are declared, but I don't show all the declarations below.

```
citiesWithBoroughs = //a global array variable, populated in a prior select: option

source: function (request, response){
    $.ajax({
        success: function ( data ){
            var geonamesResponse=$.map(data.geonames, function (item){
                return {
                    label: item.name //and others
                }
            }
            alert(citiesWithBoroughs + "," + citiesWithBoroughs.length + "|cWB2" ); //displays correct info
            var noBoroughs=$.grep( geonamesResponse, function ( item, i ) {
                for (var i=0; i < citiesWithBoroughs.length; i++ )
                if( item.label === citiesWithBoroughs[i] ){ //compare  geonamesResponse to each citiesWithBoroughs
                    console.log(citiesWithBoroughs[i]); //nothing in Console
                    return false; //drop any matches out of the geonamesResponse array
                }
                noBoroughs = $.map( data.geonames, function (item){ return item.label; });
                    console.log(noBoroughs); //nothing appears in Console
                return true;        
            });
        alert(noBoroughs.length + "," + citiesWithBoroughs.length + "," + geonamesResponse.length + "|3lengths" ); //correct info
        alert(noBoroughs + "|nB" ); //in test, shows correct number of [object,Object]  but no data
        if( noBoroughs.length != geonamesResponse.length ){
            var dropdownsCityWithBoroughs = $.grep( geonamesResponse, function ( item, i ) {
                for (var i=0; i<citiesWithBoroughs.length; i++ )
                if(item.label === citiesWithBoroughs[i]){return false;}
                return true;
            }, true )//true inverts grep to return the has-Boroughs city in the dropdown
            alert(dropdownsCityWithBoroughs + "|dCWB"); //contains object, Object, but shows no data 
            }                
        }            
    }
}
```

I'm a novice so please give specific comments and code.  I don't follow general instructions well.

Answer (score 0):

The short statement of my problem was I could not read the output of my alerts, which contain arrays.  Turns out JSON.stringify() fixes that. Other problems, like the Console.log statements not showing continue, but I can deal with that mysterious problem when the alerts work.